# Margins on horizontal borders in an Inset table

Tags: css

I have a table sitting inside a div with a colored background.  I'm using the border-style:inset for the whole table.  Each row of the table needs to have a bottom border, which I have also accomplished.  However, those bottom borders extend the full width of the table.  I'd like to have some white space on the left and right, as if the table had wide white borders on the left and right.

How can I accomplish this and preserve the inset at the same time?  The only thing I can think to do is nest everything inside an outer, one-cell table with the inset.  Is there a more elegant way?

FWIW, here's my current code:

### CSS

```
.table {
  width: 274px;
  height: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #999999;
  border-style: inset;
}

.table td {
  margin: 6px 0px 6px 10px;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 10px;
  border-bottom:thin;
  border-bottom-color: #999999;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="item" class="color1">
  <h3>TITLE</h3>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>TEXT R1<C1/td>
      <td>TEXT R1 C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEXT R2 C1</td>
      <td>TEXT RC C2</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could put

```
margin-right margin-left
```

of the table or

```
padding-left padding-right
```

depending how you want to see this blank space.